# get Publish Revision other .exe c#

Tags: c#, version, publish

How can I verify the Publish Revision version of a .exe file through another program?
I did it this way but the results are incorrect:

```
var b = path_exe; 
System.Version version = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(b).getName()Version;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following

```
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("path");
MessageBox.Show(fvi.FileVersion);
MessageBox.Show(fvi.ProductVersion);
```